# Overriding and overridden methods must have same accessibility, so why isn’t same true for Page.CreateChildControls()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, inheritance

Methods marked as `virtual` can be overridden in derived classes. One of the restrictions is that overriding and overridden methods must have same accessibility. Thus, if virtual method is marked as `protected internal`, then overriding method must also be marked as `protected internal` (it cannot be for example marked as just `protected`).

Since `Page` class overrides `Control.CreateChildControls()`, which is marked as `protected internal`, then `Page.CreateChildControls()` should also be marked as `protected internal`, but instead is marked as `protected`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably did not get your question right. This is what i found at MSDN for
[**Control.CreateChildControls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx)

```
protected internal virtual void CreateChildControls()
```

Comment: Uh, I could swear I saw on MSDN Page class defining CreateChildControls() using just protected modifier. I keep messing things up today

Comment: What you saw was right. It is Method signature and an example which are contradictory. I am confused with it as well. I probably will post a new question. with results I am getting

Comment: have posted a new poster with what more explanaition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375792/overriding-protected-internal-with-protected-how-is-this-possible

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you were looking at this incorrect example on MSDN:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{               
   // Creates a new ControlCollection. 
   this.CreateControlCollection();

   // Create child controls.
    ChildControl firstControl = new ChildControl();
   firstControl.Message = "FirstChildControl";

   ChildControl secondControl = new ChildControl();
   secondControl.Message = "SecondChildControl";

   Controls.Add(firstControl);
   Controls.Add(secondControl);

   // Prevent child controls from being created again.
   ChildControlsCreated = true;
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createcontrolcollection.aspx

Comment: Yes, for a moment I thought I was dreaming. Thanx mate