# Problems on override the Render method

Tags: c#, .net, json, render

I want to serialize all my output of a Web Form (from aspx and aspx.cs, on .NET 3.5) to JSON. So, this is my code :

```
protected string myText;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myText = "<div><span>This is my whole code</span><div><a style=\"color:blue !important;\" href=\"#\">A link</a></div></div>";
}

protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Response.Write(Request["callback"] + serializer.Serialize(writer.ToString()));
}
```

but I get this error :

```
CS0507: 'moduli_Prova.Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'System.Web.UI.Control.Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)'
```

Where am I wrong? Is this the right method to doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you have `internal` on a override

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
```

> We cannot modify the access modifiers when overriding a virtual method
>   in derived class.
>
> an override declaration cannot change the accessibility of the virtual
>   method. However, if the overridden base method is protected internal
>   and it is declared in a different assembly than the assembly
>   containing the override method then the override method’s declared
>   accessibility must be protected.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375792/overriding-protected-internal-with-protected)

Maybe something like this:

```
protected override void Render (HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb));
    //Render the page to the new HtmlTextWriter which actually writes to the stringbuilder
    base.Render(tw);

    //Get the rendered content
    string sContent = sb.ToString();

    //Now output it to the page, if you want
    writer.Write(sContent);
}
```

**Edit**

We know that all pages inherit from `page`.. We also know that a new `htmltextwriter` take in a `stringwriter` that has a `stringbuilder` in the contructor. When we then call the base class (`page`) to render the html to our new `HtmlTextWriter`. It render it too the `htmltextwriter` that also renders to the `stringbuilder`. So now we have the html context in our `stringbuilder`. Then we just say to the inputed `HtmlTextWriter` that is should write the `string` from our `stringbuilder`.

Reference [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t106472-how-to-capture-the-rendered-html-for-asp-net-page.html)

Comment: Right! But unfortunatly this print `request?"System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter"`, not the output of web form converted to JSON :O

Comment: @markzzz, because you're writing the object itself, not it's output.

Comment: uhm? So, how can I get the output? from that object I suppose? I don't see any method that doing it...

Comment: Can you help me? How can I access to the output?

Comment: Not sure about you have done it...but it ROCKS! Thank you...master! P.S. Can you explain in details how you have done it? And how it works? Would be a nice document, also for the future...

Comment: Update the answer. I hope it help you understand